# Failed to rotate logs using built-in Rails logger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

**development.rb:**

```
GDisp::Application.configure do
    config.logger = Logger.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'development.log'), 20, 10240000)
end
```

**Errors:**

```
log shifting failed. Permission denied - (D:/Work/disp/log/development.log, D:/Work/disp/log/development.log.0)
log writing failed. closed stream
log shifting failed. closed stream
log writing failed. closed stream
log shifting failed. closed stream
log writing failed. closed stream
```

development.rb is 10001 kb long.

Windows 7 x64

Comment: This could be related: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7303

Comment: @Prakash Murthy: Thank you. The issue has been confirmed 2 years ago and still not fixed in out-of-the-box version!

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware this is a VERY old issue. However I found the issue and rectified the problem.

The issue is due to Windows having a file association - You need to remove the file association for each of the `.log` and `.0` / `.1` / `.2` e.t.c. files

I did this by editing my registry, the files to edit are available here: (**Note I'm on Win7 at work!**)
http://www.howtogeek.com/171932/how-do-you-remove-a-default-file-association-in-windows-7/

Once you've done this, it might need a restart of the programs, but once done, it will shift correctly. You may also need to manually shift the offending file (If it was the .0 file that you had to remove the reference to)

Cheers,

Luke

Comment: Thank you for your effort and readiness to help, but I am sorry to say two things: 1. I never had any associations for `.0`, `.1`, `.2` etc. file extensions in Windows Registry neither in HKLM nor in HKCU. 2. I am temporarily out of Ruby and Rails subjects for several years so I cannot check your answer right now.